# How to limit Chart.js label length on axes without affecting tooltips

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to substring label text on XAxis since they are too long. Also the label is shown when mouse is hovering on a bar. The problem is when I substring label, both side of text is affected which I don't want. I just want to substring the text on XAxis. Is that possible?

Here is code I am using:

```
var memX = [];
var memY = [];

$(data.mem).each(function() {
    memX.push(splitLabel(this.name));
    memY.push(this.cnt);
});

var memData = { 
    labels: memX, 
    datasets: [{ label:'Members', data: memY, borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'rgba(125, 199, 85, 0.7)' }] };

    new Chart(document.getElementById(id + '_members'), { 
    type: 'bar', 
    data: memData, 
    options: { 
        responsive: true, 
        scales: { 
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 500
        }
    }
});
```

Here is screen shot:

[image]

Comment: The blue box on the image which is appeared when hovering mouse cursor.

Comment: um.. I mean what should be the x-axis labels after substring?

Comment: I just want it to be shorter since some labels are too long. For example, one of my label is "Corporate Membership(Active)" and I just want it to be something like "Corporate" but in the popup box showing full text "Corporate Membership(Active)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!** That is possible.

As it seems from the screenshot given, you are using multi-line labels. If that is the case then, you can use the following x-axis ticks and tooltips callback functions to trim the labels on x-axis and show the complete text on tooltips respectively.

**x-axis ticks callback** *(for trimming labels)*

```
xAxes: [{
   ticks: {
      callback: function(label) {
         return label[0];
      }
   }
}]
```

**tooltips title callback** *(for showing complete text)*

```
tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
      title: function(t, d) {
         return d.labels[t[0].index];
      }
   }
}
```

---

**working example :**

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: [
         ['Corporate', 'Membership', '(Active)'],
         ['Group', 'Membership', '(Active)'],
         ['Muncipal', 'Level 2', '(300000-499999)', '(Active)'],
         ['Muncipal', 'Level 5', '(100000-399999)', '(Active)'],
         ['University', 'Membership', '(Active)']
      ],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Members',
         data: [2, 4, 1, 3, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(2, 215, 6, 0.3)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(2, 215, 6, 0.4)',
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               callback: function(label) {
                  return label[0];
               }
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      },
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            title: function(t, d) {
               return d.labels[t[0].index];
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```